# Python 3 - ascii to hex for hmac

Tags: python, hmac

I'm having an issue and not quite sure how to explain it but I will try my best.

So I'm attempting to authenticate with an API which requires grabbing a private key that is provided by the website in hex representation (e.g. an example token is "665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569") and decode to ascii to create a keyed hash so I may pass it in an http header which is part of the authentication process.

When it comes to python2 I can simply

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests


headers = {
           "custom header": hmac.new("665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569".decode("hex"),
                                     msg="whatever",
                                     digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
          }
requests.get("my url", headers=headers)
```

However, I cannot get this working in python3 despite several hours of googling, various SO posts and looking at the official docs for hmac.

This seems to stem from the differences between how python2 and 3 handle strings.

In python2 running `"665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569".decode("hex")` returns this string of characters "f\ ��Q~S�?ۛM   -0�V��GE�i" which is passed to hmac.new()

Somethings I have tried in Python3 after searching around:

```
bytes.fromhex('665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569').decode('utf-8')

bytes.fromhex('665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569').decode('ascii')

import binascii
binascii.unhexlify(b"665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569")
```

But these all error or output different returns that hmac.new() won't accept. I'm assuming there's a simple fix that I'm just ignorant on since I'm not very knowledgeable about the nuances of how p2 and p3 handle strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your attempts is correct:

```
In [1]: import binascii
   ...: binascii.unhexlify(b"665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569")
   ...:
Out[1]: b'f\\ \xb3\xc4Q~\x02S\x11\x16\x0b\x7f\xec?\xdb\x9bM\t\x1f\x14-0\x8cV\x8d\x0e\xecGE\xf5i'
```

If you get a wrong result from `hmac` afterwards, you can post a question about that specific scenario, with some examples comparing python2/3.

You may be running into a problem with the message itself, which needs to explicitly use bytes, not a string. These two give the same values:

Python 3:

```
In [10]: hmac.new(binascii.unhexlify(b"665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569"),
    ...:   msg="whatever".encode('utf-8'),
    ...:   digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
Out[10]: '79ca98357629c22a094c67a02638076573ec41d2c5ce8996435656f8488552d0'
```

Python 2:

```
>>> hmac.new("665c20b3c4517e025311160b7fec3fdb9b4d091f142d308c568d0eec4745f569".decode("hex"),
...                                      msg="whatever",
...                                      digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
'79ca98357629c22a094c67a02638076573ec41d2c5ce8996435656f8488552d0'
```

Comment: That was it! What I was missing when trying to use binascii was `.encode('utf-8')` for the msg argument in python3. Thank you very much!

Comment: @poply Great. Just remember that the `utf-8` is just my example. You'll have to use your actual encoding there, or `bytes` directly.